# When trying to open up/run eclipse, I get the "Java was started but returned exit code"

Tags: java, eclipse

I've just started to learn Java and I'm encountering a problem in starting Eclipse. It says:

> Java was started but returned exit code = 13

and a bit more. Please help me find a solution, thanks!

Comment: oh, and preferrably try to keep it simple

Comment: `I'm just starting to learn Java` - lesson 0: java is java, javascript is javascript, the two are in no way related :p

Comment: @JaromandaX You're absolutely wrong. They're both brewed from coffee :-). Oh, and also that when Netscape "created" JavaScript it collaborated with Sun Systems (the owner of Java) and requested it to have similar syntax to Java. So they are related :-) That was back in 1995 though, and the two relatives immigrated to different countries and have never seen each other since :-)

Comment: @RacilHilan - I suck at genealogy :p

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might possibly get solved by one of the following:

1. Create an environment variable to Windows properties variable name = PATH variable value = `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin`, not to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`.
2. `Program Files (x86)` is the folder where 64-bit Windows places 32-bit programs. `Program Files` is the folder where 64-bit Windows places 64-bit programs. Your version of Eclipse might be 64-bit while the version of Java might be 32-bit, or vice-versa
3. Specify the JVM path in eclipse.ini